# What is the proper way to assess the presence of an interaction of two categorical variables?

Tags: r, categorical-data, interaction, linear-model, paired-data

### Main question

Assume that one can administer a treatment to patients in two different conditions. What is the proper way to conclude (or reject) that the treatment response behaves differently in the two conditions?

---

### Details

I have a visual representation of the data given by this R code:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
            treatment = factor(rep(c('A', 'B'), 6)),
            condition = factor(rep(paste0('C', rep(1:2, each = 2)), 3)),
            patient = factor(rep(1:3, each = 4)),
            value = c(-0.0639702087518468, -0.167423223114275, -0.317149084387659,
                      0.0210959460693152, -0.149081608366965, -0.209808475835088,
                      -0.202405623531127, -0.356739500420453, 0.00963949693008453,
                      0.054140408007695, -0.127847368642939, 0.0174879908023845))

avg_data <- data %>% 
                group_by(treatment, condition) %>% 
                    summarise(value = mean(value))

eps <- 0.125

ggplot(data, aes(x = treatment, y = value)) + 
    geom_line(aes(color = patient, group = patient)) + 
    geom_point(size = 5, aes(color = patient)) + 
    geom_hline(data = avg_data, aes(yintercept = value), linetype = 'dashed') +
    geom_segment(data = avg_data, linewidth = 2,
                 aes(x = unclass(treatment) - eps,
                 xend = unclass(treatment) + eps, 
                 yend = value)) +
    facet_wrap(~ condition)
```

Which produces the following plot (orange arrows where drawn manually):
[image: paired_plot_in_two_conditions]

Now, visually it looks like the treatment responses (orange arrows) behave differently in condition `C1` (average values get slightly lower) compared to `C2` (average values increase). Assuming a linear model, I hoped to see a significant interaction term between the two factors `condition` and `treatment`, but the line `lm(value ~ treatment * condition, data = data)`
yields a p-value of $p = 0.639$ an adj. R-squared of $\bar{R}^2 = -0.126$. 
Even if I compare it to a simpler linear model without interaction term, via

```r
fit_interaction <- lm(value ~ treatment * condition, data = data)
fit_base <- lm(value ~ treatment + condition, data = data)
anova(fit_base, fit_interaction)
```

I get a p-value of $p = 0.393$.

Including `patient` as a confounding factor, by putting it as an additional covariant (i.e. adding `+ patient` in all of the formulas above) slightly increases p-values but is still far away from significance.

**My question now is**: Are the two arrows, despite visual suspicion, simply not significantly different or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you really only have 3 patients, or have you simplified the data here?

Comment: That's the actual data I have to work with... just 3 patients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a paired-subjects design, the correct analysis would be either a linear mixed model with random intercept terms,

```r
lmer(value ~ treatment * condition + (1|patient), data = data)
```

or a t-test on each patient's difference scores

```r
wide_data = data %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = treatment, values_from = value) %>%
  mutate(delta = B - A)
t.test(delta ~ condition, data = wide_data, paired = TRUE)
```

However, the real issue here is that with only three patients it's almost impossible to draw conclusions from the data unless results are extremely consistent across patients (and even then it's very unlikely that anything will be statistically significant).